# Cannot Get Latest Conda Release (V 4.6.1 with upgraded PowerShell Initialization Support) To Work with PowerShell (Ideally to Integrate with VSCode)

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda, miniconda

The latest release of Conda (4.6.1) asserts added initialization support, especially making reference to PowerShell. [As can be seen in this official update release documentation](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/conda-4-6-release/)

However, upon upgrade and initialization setup:

```
conda update conda

conda init
```

Producing this output:

```
C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\Scripts\conda-env.exe
C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py
C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\Scripts\conda-env-script.py
C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\condabin\conda.bat
C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\Library\bin\conda.bat
C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\condabin\_conda_activate.bat
C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\condabin\conda_auto_activate.bat
C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\condabin\conda_hook.bat
C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\condabin\activate.bat
C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\condabin\deactivate.bat
C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\Scripts\activate
C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\Scripts\deactivate
C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\etc\profile.d\conda.sh
C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\etc\fish\conf.d\conda.fish
C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1
C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1
C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\xonsh\conda.xsh
C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\etc\profile.d\conda.csh
C:\Users\User\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
```

(Making sure to reload a new shell session as instructed)
When I attempt to initialize in PowerShell, I get this error message upon immediately loading PowerShell (prior to attempting conda activate myenv):

```
. : File C:\Users\User\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because running
scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:3
+ . 'C:\Users\User\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_p ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Based on [This link to the Microsoft Execution Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-5.1) it appears to be a security issue. I'm assuming Conda has submitted the proper publishing certifications, however despite the above conda init output showing amendment to the PowerShell_profile.ps1 file (second last line in the above 'conda init' output), I cannot get conda to initialize in PowerShell.

[This link instructs on how to manually set the Execution Policy for RemoteSigned](https://www.faqforge.com/windows/windows-powershell-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system/)

Instructing:

```
Run shell as Administrator.
> Get-ExecutionPolicy
> Set-ExecutionPolicy remoteSigned
Done.

To Undo
> Set-ExecutionPolicy restricted
```

[And provides a link to the official Microsoft.PowerShell.Security Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Security/Set-ExecutionPolicy?view=powershell-5.1)

[And as I already documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-5.1)

However, I'm hesitant to make the manual adjustments as I have run into issues with setting the policy in the past, and am concerned that it will make more of a mess of things than clean up the PowerShell integration issues, particularly considering the latest conda release was intended to do this structurally/natively.

Is it possible that I simply need to update my PowerShell? I have Windows 10 and am running PowerShell version 5.1.

Any help would be very much appreciated as I am dying to have conda integrated in Visual Studio Code terminal.

Comment: The issue is your profile cannot be imported and I assume the Conda is adding the integrations there. In order for this to work you'll have to enable PowerShell to allow the execution of scripts. I would recommend enabling the execution of script and then the profile should load without issues.

Comment: It works as you reassured and as the links I provided instruct. Thanks very much. Can we anticipate that Set-ExecutionPolicy will be unnecessary in future releases? It seems like a security hole and Microsoft is playing nice with conda/opensource now with VSCode.

Comment: I would find that unlikely as part of the philosophy behind the execution policy was to add a barrier for using PowerShell scripts as malware or accidental execution.