# Conda Not Able to Install Conda-forge Packages After Updating Conda to 4.6.1 to Integrate PowerShell

Tags: python, powershell, visual-studio-code, conda, miniconda

The latest release of Conda (4.6.1) asserts added initialization support, especially making reference to PowerShell. [As can be seen in this official update release documentation](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/conda-4-6-release/)

I detail the update and initialization process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429536/cannot-get-latest-conda-release-v-4-6-1-with-upgraded-powershell-initialization?noredirect=1#comment95671251_54429536) (as I ran into an issue with Microsoft/PowerShell requiring to Set-ExecutionPolicy remoteSigned during coding session).

I can set it up and integrate it with Visual Studio Code, however I am now running into an issue where I cannot install packages from Conda-forge into any of my conda environments.

Below is an output of the error I get:

```
(p3environ_test) C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\envs\p3environ_test>conda install -c conda-forge numpy
Collecting package metadata: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))
```

Although it seems to be a one-off event, I also encountered an issue simply trying to create a python 3 environment, wherein the error output was as follows:

```
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python-3.6

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I am guessing that the latest release of Conda (V.4.6.1) has a bug, or it is a Conda-forge channel issue (maybe they have not accounted for the update here?)?

I reloaded my prior version of Conda (4.5) and had no issue with either creating environments or installing conda-forge packages.

A similar incident has been noted by someone [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7043) during a previous upgrade and I am wondering if it is an issue with the channels.  In the link, special note is made to adding channels.  As you might be able to guess, I'm a conda newbie (or at least lack proficiency) and so don't know how to manually make adjustments to channels or if I should (would this create issues down the road for me upon newer conda updates?) Conda-forge has simply worked for me in the past without any channel adjustments.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a small troubleshooting update in case anybody wants to be apprised, I found this bug report on github that I believe it might account for the error I'm encountering: [GitHub Bug Report](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7172)

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: I solved a similar problem of mine by installing [OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html). Specifically, I downloaded version 1.1.1a, 64-bit (`Win64OpenSSL-1_1_1a.exe`) and installed it with the default installation parameters, i.e. I chose to copy the OpenSSL DLLs to "The Windows system directory".

More details:

- I had a similar headache with *a fresh install (!)* of Anaconda3. In my case, in a (conda's) virtual environment I could not `conda install` anything, and kept getting SSL errors similar to yours.
- Several people recommended `conda config --set ssl_verify False`, but it sounds like an awful and dangerous hack (+someone somewhere said that this led to problems installing certain packages).
- Someone [else](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/3292#issuecomment-387233542) recommended to `set REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=path\to\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem`, but it didn't work for me. (I also tried setting it as an Environment Variable, also didn't work)
- All in all, installing OpenSSL (see above) solved it for me.

Bonus tips, maybe relevant to similar problems:

1. Some things are easier from an Anaconda Prompt (as opposed to a normal Command Prompt).
2. If you just installed a fresh Anaconda, do yourself a favor and *restart* your Windows, even if the post-installation does not require you to.

Comment: I installed OpenSSL as advised, and my former error same as the one in the question has been turned into the following error:
`Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way. `
[to be continued]

Comment: `If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64' `