# problem getting build dependencies from conda in vscode build task OSX Catalina

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, build, anaconda, conda

I *used to* have a simple setup for debugging a C++ project built with scons with dependencies provided by conda where I would run a build task like the following:

```
{
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "build proj debug",
            "command": "scons",
            "args": [
                "-j8",
                "debug=1"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
```

I run this as a prelaunch build task. Now, for whatever reason, the scons messages printed to terminal match those I would get if I called scons from the wrong environment. That is to say, it looks like it is not activating conda specifically in the terminal that is created for the above build task. The output is project specific, but if you know scons it is what happens if you have 0 of the build dependencies available for the project you're trying to compile. This implies that some version of scons is being run, but it doesn't have the libraries in its search paths, which the conda env I use provides.

I have tried setting the python.pythonPath to `path/to/my/conda/env/bin/python`. I have also tried the various suggestions on the vscode documentation about setting up my vscode executable to either be inherited from the shell I call `code` from to open the workspace, and this actually makes it worse because it then gives:

```
> Executing task: scons -j8 debug=1 <

zsh:1: command not found: scons
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 127

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

instead of errors implying that the base miniconda I used is active, which is what happens in the original case. I have also tried eliminating the input args using the the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52601198/vscode-virtual-studio-code-unable-to-load-conda-environment-in-vscode-termina), in the answer about macs. Same result.

If I execute `scons -j8 debug=1` from the terminal in the project directory with the conda env I need activated the project builds without complaint.

There's something wrong with my integrated terminal though, because if I simply open it and ask for the python version get the following:

```
(proj) myname@x86_64-apple-darwin13 proj % python --version
Python 2.7.16
(proj) myname@x86_64-apple-darwin13 proj %
```

However if I'm in the terminal.app, that is to say a context where everything appears to be working normally, I get:

```
(proj) myname@x86_64-apple-darwin13 loos % python --version
Python 3.8.0
(proj) myname@x86_64-apple-darwin13 loos %
```

This being the expected version number for the conda env I'm working out of.

I'm at a bit of a loss here, but am aware I may need to provide more info to get help. I'd be happy to provide that if requested.

Comment: Bump...this is still a problem. I still don't know how to make sure my 'proj' env is active for the build on mac.