# Vscode uses wrong terminal when running python code

Tags: python, terminal, visual-studio-code

I always used the "Run python file in terminal"-button in Vscode, but some recent update seems to have broken it for me. My default terminal is cmd, but when I use the button, it now uses powershell and does not activate the conda environment, which prevents my code from running.
[image]

When I open up a new terminal manually, it rightfully uses cmd, activates the env and `python <path>`  works again.
This is the output after pressing the run-button:
[image]

Does anyone know how to set the button to use cmd?

Comment: this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52601198/vscode-virtual-studio-code-unable-to-load-conda-environment-in-vscode-termina?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode / Virtual Studio Code: Unable to Load Conda Environment in VSCode Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52601198/vscode-virtual-studio-code-unable-to-load-conda-environment-in-vscode-termina)

Comment: This is an old solution, which I used before. Vscode now flags these setting parameters as deprecated and tells me to change the setting above now.
I tried the solution just to be sure, to no effect.

Comment: I am wondering if it is a side affect of the known bug currently in the 1.60 release: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69047142/vscode-is-suddenly-defaulting-to-powershell-for-integrated-terminal-and-tasks

Comment: do Stackoverflow have some kind of bot because I didnt typed the second comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue of `Python Extension`. And it should be fixed tomorrow with the new release. You can refer to [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/132150) for more details.

And have you add `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,` in the settings.json file? Because it's weird, as the cmd activates the environment while the Powershell does not.